# Which Amazon EC2 AMI to use for cross browser testing?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Which Amazon EC2 AMI should I use for cross browser testing? I'd like to test on IE6, IE7 and IE8 (using a Mac), and would like an AMI with sensible settings, and perhaps something like Superpreview or IETester preinstalled.

Comment: Hello, what will you be testing? Just standard webpage that can be served by apache? What apache mods do you require etc.

Comment: I'm doing cross browser testing - IE6, IE7, IE8, the others I can do on my mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a set of AMIs that cover all versions of IE. There are available in the us-east region.

http://www.hens-teeth.net/cross-browser-testing

Answer (score 2):

If you only do this a few times a year, it might be more cost effective to try one of the cross-browser testing services that are already out there.  Here are a couple:

- [CrossBrowserTesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/)
- [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)
- [Browsera](http://www.browsera.com/)
- [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/)
- [Review of cross-browser test tools and services](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/04/cross-browser-testing-a-detailed-review-of-tools-and-services/)

Good luck !

Comment: I added BrowserStack to this.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is not to use any. Instead, install http://www.virtualbox.org/ which will allow you to virtualise Windows; this means that Windows will literally run in a window on your Mac OSX desktop; and you can install whatever browser you want on it. We do this routinely.

Comment: I'm considering this, but it'll set me back $100+ for a windows license, and I do this only a few times a year.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the official MS Virtual pc images ? MS provide them for testing browser compatibility.
Using virtualbox as underlined in a previous post you should be able to load them.